# Horizontal scroll bar is not working in Protractor - Fifefox browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, jasmine, protractor

Unable to scroll horizontally in fifefox browsr(working fine in Chrome..)

```
Fifefox version :45
Node :v6.9.4
Protractor : 5.0.0

browser.actions().mouseMove(element.all(by.binding('labels.QUANTITY')).get(0)).perform();
```

Please share me if any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shouldn't use `mouseMove( location, opt_offset ) → ActionSequence`. this will just move the mouse to that particular element and doesn't always guarantee a scroll.

In case you want to scroll till end of the window

```
browser.executeScript('return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth').then(function(width){
    return browser.executeScript('return window.scrollTo(0,arguments[0]);',width);
})
```

in case you want to scroll to a particular element

```
element(by.css('#twitter-widget-0')).getLocation().then(function(loc){
    return browser.executeScript('return window.scrollTo(arguments[0],arguments[1]);',loc.x,loc.y);
})
```